# If $X_0,X_1,X_2,...$ are IID random variables and uniform on $S^1$, then so are $X_0+X_1,X_0+X_2,...$?

Tags: probability, independence

Given that $(X_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ are IID random variables with $X_n \sim \space \text{Uni}(S^1)$, what is a nice way (or hint) to show that $(X_0 + X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are also IID with distribution $\text{Uni}(S^1)$?

The fact that they are all identically distributed with distribution $\text{Uni}(S^1)$ part is straight forward, it's essentially just a convolution. But I'm not sure how to show independence?

Comment: Context for this question please. Meanwhile I am sure this question is a duplicate but I do not have specific links

Comment: Write $X_n = Z_n/\|Z_n\|$ for $Z_n$ standard gaussian

Comment: What is $S^1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Fourier transform for the group $S_1$, and $E(e^{inX_j})=0$ if $n\neq 0$ and $1$ if $n=0$, or $\delta(n).$ If $Y_j=X_0+X_j$ then
$$E(e^{i\sum_{j=1}^kn_jY_j})=\delta(n_1+\cdots+n_k) \delta(n_1)\ldots \delta(n_k)= \delta(n_1)\ldots \delta(n_k)$$
$$ E(e^{in_j Y_j})=\delta(n_j)^2=\delta(n_j).$$

Therefore $$\prod_j E(e^{in_j Y_j})=\delta(n_1)\ldots \delta(n_k)=E(e^{i\sum_{j=1}^kn_jY_j})$$ which proves the independence of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_k.$